# Numpy import in PyCharm yields "Cannot locate working compiler"

Tags: compiler-construction, numpy, python-3.x, pycharm

I am new to Python and PyCharm, installed PyCharm 2.6 (on Mac OSX) and tried to import NumPy for Python 3.3. JetBrains support file tells me to install Cython which also yields "Cannot locate working compiler"

How and which compiler do I need to install?

Thanks!

Comment: **PyCharm 3.3** ?? Their latest version **[is only 2.6](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)**. Possibly you meant to say Python 3.3 ?

Comment: Correct... Just edited my post. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Does it work from the terminal? Make sure you have XCode command line tools installed. Also try running PyCharm from the terminal to get the same environment where compiler could be found: `open -a /Applications/PyCharm.app/`

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What exactly IS the 'gcc' command? And how exactly do I change the CC environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the 'gcc' command works. If it's there, try setting the CC environment variable to 'gcc'.